# if-not one-liners to avoid repetitive blocks, a matter of python style

Tags: python, coding-style

I am working on a personal API project that involves accepting requests with keywords many of which are required. Because of this I find myself writing defensively with a lot of code that looks like this:

```
def post(self, urlSafeKey=None):
    if urlSafeKey:
       # do a bunch 
       # of stuff
       # here
    else:
       self.abort(400, detail="A key parameter is required")
```

I've been told to prefer `if - else` over testing negatives with `if not` for readability but when I go through and change all these blocks to something like this…

```
def post(self, urlSafeKey=None):
    if not urlSafeKey: self.abort(400, detail="A key parameter is required")
    # do a bunch 
    # of stuff
    # here
```

…it looks cleaner and shorter, but I worry that it's an annoying stylistic habit and in the end might be less clear.

Is there a consensus on this in the Python world?

Comment: I generally follow the second style, with _all_ the condition checks at the beginning so there are no nasty surprise later.  Also an alternative is to split off the actual logic into an unsafe function which `post` would call (you can call the unsafe one `_post` or `_unsafe_post`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `self.abort` raises an exception (and thus terminates function `post`), I do believe it's best to avoid nesting the normal-case code inside an `if`.  `import this` at an interactive interpreter prompt to be reminded of the "Zen of Python", one of whose koans is "flat is better than nested":-).

As for the one-liner

```
if not urlSafeKey: self.abort(400, detail="A key parameter is required")
```

it's a bit long for my personal tastes -- I prefer `if`-based one liners to be limited to very short and concise cases, such as `if cond: return`, `if cond: continue`, `if cond: break`, and otherwise use two lines.  But this is really a minor (purely lexical!) issue compared with preferring the avoidance of nesting (i.e, check for "I'm done" conditions and exit the function or loop as early as you know it's done), which **is** a Python-Zen-level issue!-)

Answer (score 2):

In general, following the best practice is `best practice`. I don't recommend oneline statements.  But I see nothing wrong with testing for `not urlSafeKey`.

```
def post(self, urlSafeKey=None):
    if not urlSafeKey:
       self.abort(400, detail="A key parameter is required")
    # do a bunch 
    # of stuff
    # here
```